# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint nd on network nat: HNS failed with error : Unspecified error

Tags: docker

I stuck while doing this docker tutorial:

https://blog.sixeyed.com/dockerizing-nerd-dinner-part-1-running-a-legacy-asp-net-app-in-a-windows-container/

Problems started after using this command:

`docker run -d -p 80:8081 --name nd sixeyed/nerd-dinner:part1`

the result is:

```
36a395f0c02dc0bccc0e50d108c277043866aa030f8393b4ad9a7590c573a05d
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from 
daemon: failed to create endpoint nd on network nat: HNS failed with error : 
Unspecified error.
```

I tried to do this on my 2nd computer, and everything works fine.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 2):

May something is already runing on host-machine's port 80.

Can you try to switch it to any other port like 8081 or 9090.

```
#>docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nd sixeyed/nerd-dinner:part1
or 
#>docker run -d -P --name nd sixeyed/nerd-dinner:part1
```